# Alternative ways to pick param values from URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to parse URLs and get parameter values that are in certain locations in the URL. I've come up with one way to handle this and wanted to get suggestions on alternative and hopefully more efficient ways to achieve the same results.

Say the URL is: `http://myUrl.com/route1/param1/param2`

My current approach is:

```
var segments = myUrl.split('/');
var i = segments.length;
var param1 = segments[i-2];
var param2 = segments[i-1];
```

I'd appreciate suggestions for alternative and more efficient ways of getting parameters from URLs.

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? In what way do you want it to be better? It's very unlikely to get more efficient, and even less likely that this is an area where you need to maximize efficiency.

Comment: Find an appropriate library.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nothing's wrong with my approach. I just want to explore alternative ways that could do the job more efficiently.

Comment: Your way is perfectly, I wouldn't look to maximise efficiency over readability.   You could potentially shave some lines using `segments.pop()` to get the last parameter each time, if you don't mind mutating the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array destructuring to get the elements. But because the rest parameter (`...`) can only be last you have to reverse the array.

```js
const url = 'http://myUrl.com/route1/param1/param2';

const [param2, param1] = url.split('/').reverse();

console.log(param1, param2);
```